# How to change colour or remove headers on Bigcartel

Tags: html, css, bigcartel

I'm trying to change the colour or remove the word Entry(header) in the top left of my bigcartel http://pafclub.bigcartel.com/entry so the page is completely white. i want it to effect just this page without changing colours for other things on the other pages which is what happens when you use the default header colour changer.

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link to the site 
that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value to future visitors once 
the problem is solved or if the site you're linking to is inaccessible. Posting a 
[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (MCVE)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that 
demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, see 
[Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) 
Thanks!

Comment: I get what ur saying but there was no code to show, my bigcartel uses a default theme and the headers come with it, i just needed to know how to remove them. so there was nothing wrong with the code the site didn't need fixing, i just didn't have the technical know how to remove the headers that are there by default and wanted to know if others knew how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `<body>` tag gets a unique ID attribute for every page, so to target the page title (and hide it) only on your Entry page you can add a bit of CSS. Head to Customize Design > Advanced > CSS and add this code in at the very bottom:

```
#entry h1 { display: none }
```